# Use --config-setting in tox

Tags: python, tox

In [tox](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox), I'd like to build my package with a certain [pypa-build](https://github.com/pypa/build) [`--config-setting`](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#python--m-build---config-setting). Any idea how to specify it?

Comment: Do you want to replace the current build backend of tox which is not build, or do you want to run build as command in an env? The latter should be straightforward, the former would quite possible need a custom plugin, and maybe even new hooks. I would suggest that you either join the toy discord channel (discord.gg/tox) or the discussions on the GitHub project to discuss details.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed they use build. Let me move the discord, thanks for pointer!